# How can I dismiss NSPopover when not active?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a menu bar app that displays an NSPopover when the status icon is pressed. The problem is that it will only close if you click again on the status icon.

I want the view to close when I click anywhere outside the popover itself.

I tried changing the popovers attributes `Behaviour` to `Transient` but the issue persists.

What is the best way I can achieve this?

Answer (score -3):

Use UIPopoverController instead of NSPopover and Present it in the required ViewController using the below method

```
    - (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So if any other view is clicked apart from the popover, it will dismiss automatically.